# ES6 code completion (Intellisense) with composition in VSCode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, intellisense, composition

I am trying to get code completion to work when nesting classes in es6 using the following syntax: `class Dog extends FoodMixin(Animal)`. The first implementation works fine, giving me auto completion for both FoodMixin and Animal. However, if I nest it one deeper, or apply a second mixin, the auto completion stops. For instance: `class Dog extends OtherMixin(FoodMixin(Animal))` will lose the code completion for the FoodMixin class.

Is there a way I can have intellisense work for both OtherMixin and FoodMixin?

**Simple test code:**

```
const FoodMixin = superclass => class extends superclass {
    eat() {
        console.log("Eating");
    }
};

const OtherMixin = superclass => class extends superclass {
    test() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
};

class Animal {
}

class Dog extends OtherMixin(FoodMixin(Animal)){
}

const dog = new Dog();
dog.test(); //INTELLISENSE WORKS
dog.eat(); //INTELLISENSE DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but there is probably something to be said for not using inheritance this way. Inheritance chains like this typically lead to code that is difficult to test and maintain. There is lots of literature on composition vs inheritance if you're interested in learning further.

Comment: I suggest you never write code like the above example.  You are trying to mix composition and inheritance in a way that vscode and humans have trouble understanding. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @Peter Gotcha, so that means that the following tutorial that I was following is suggesting bad practices: https://alligator.io/js/class-composition/ ?

If so, how would I follow a composition pattern using ES6 that supports intellisense? I can't seem to find a good tutorial..

Comment: visit https://codesanitize.com/es6-also-known-as-ecmascript-2015-a-javascript-language-update/

Answer (score 2):

VS Code's JavaScript IntelliSense will not be able to understand very dynamic code like that example. The tutorial you linked to that provided this code is being too clever for its own (or really anyone's) good.

However you can sort of workaround VS Code's limitation by adding explicit type annotations for the types and interfaces used in the example using JSDoc:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{ eat(): void }} Eater
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{ test(): void }} Tester
 */

/**
 * @type {Dog & Eater & Tester}
 */
const dog = new Dog();
dog.
```

[image]

The `&` is not standard JS Doc type syntax but an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) from TypeScript. (I am using it here because it mimics composition)